# invalidating query cache entries(key)

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.0

when I tried to delete some records from a MYSQL server  (version 5.0.95-log)  and checked the process list I got  the result as follows

```
mysql> show processlist \G
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 3480
   User: admin
   Host:
     db: test_db1
Command: Connect
   Time: 8367
  State: invalidating query cache entries (key)
   Info: NULL
```

I  would like know what is this "invalidating query cache entries (key)" and is this due to any configuration settings.Replication is configured in this machine and it acts as the Master Server.

Please find the my.cnf file setting blow

```
[mysqld]

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
lower_case_table_names = 1
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G
innodb_log_file_size=512M
query_cache_size=512M
table_cache=64
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

#Replication 

log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1
sync_binlog=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

binlog-do-db=test_db1
binlog-do-db=test_db2

# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log

pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```