# InnoDB SELECT from disk slow for large table but MyISAM is fast

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm having problems determining why a simple MySQL select query on an indexed, fairly large InnoDB table is taking so long for the first run, reading from the HDD (3-4 seconds)

However, switching the table to MyISAM, the same query is very quick for the first run (200-400 ms)

I tried importing the data into SQL Server on a slower Windows machine and the query was also quick.

Here's a somewhat stripped down version of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE memberclaim (
  ClaimNumber bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PayerCode bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  MemberNumber bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PayerProviderNumber bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PayerProviderIndex int(11) NOT NULL,
  ClaimDate date NOT NULL,
  PaidDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  ServiceFrom date NOT NULL,
  ServiceTo date NOT NULL,
  TotalPaid decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  ProviderClaimID char(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ClaimNumber),
  UNIQUE KEY PayerCode (PayerCode,ProviderClaimID),
  KEY idx_MemberNumber (MemberNumber, ServiceFrom, ServiceTo),
  KEY idx_bypayerprovider (PayerProviderNumber, PayerProviderIndex)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here's an example of a query being run:

```
SELECT MC.ClaimNumber,
       MC.PayerProviderNumber,
       MC.PayerProviderIndex,
       MC.ClaimDate,
       MC.PaidDate,
       MC.ServiceFrom,
       MC.ServiceTo,
       MC.TotalPaid,
       MC.ProviderClaimID
FROM memberclaim MC
WHERE MC.MemberNumber = 1234 AND
      MC.ServiceTo >= '2016-01-01' AND
      MC.ServiceFrom <= '2017-01-01';
```

Some background:

We're running MySQL 5.7.17 on Linux. I'm running this with mostly default MySQL settings, with the innodb_buffer_pool set to 7GB (not that it matters much in this case).

The table has about 35 million rows.

The server has 16 GB of RAM, 4 2.4 GHz processors, and an HDD (an SSD would obviously be much quicker).

This table is only written to at night, not when the system is in use.

The query is perfectly fine once cached, but we don't have nearly enough RAM on the server to cache everything and the vast majority of runs of this query are with unique MemberNumbers.

I've tried dumping and importing the entire table and that made no difference.

Are there any real options to speed up this query besides getting an SSD or switching it to MyISAM?

Any settings I should try modified that can speed up the disk access?

I've already read:
[Why are simple SELECTs on InnoDB 100x slower than on MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75091/why-are-simple-selects-on-innodb-100x-slower-than-on-myisam) and nothing in that post helped unfortunately.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

*Edit*

This query returns a few hundred rows generally, around 100-300 and takes a few seconds to finish.

By unique MemberNumber, I just meant that the MemberNumber field in the WHERE clause is the field that changes and the query has to read from  the disk constantly because of that.

The nightly runs are just inserts (tens of thousands of records) and a much smaller number of updates.

key_buffer_size = 1GB

SHOW TABLE STATUS results:

```
Name        Engine  Version Row_format  Rows       Avg_row_length   Data_length Max_data_length Index_length    Data_free   Auto_increment  Create_time           Update_time   Check_time  Collation   Checksum    Create_options  Comment
memberclaim InnoDB   10     Compact     30300000   160              4857004032  0               4823449600      5295308800  35137097        8/28/2014 12:38:44 PM                           latin1_swedish_ci
```

Here's the explain on the above SELECT statement, which returns 123 rows and took 2.265 seconds:

```
id    select_type    table    type    possible_keys    key              key_len       ref    rows     Extra
1     SIMPLE         MC       range   idx_MemberNumber idx_MemberNumber 11                   254      Using where
```

Here's the results of SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%'

```
Variable_name               Value
Handler_commit              1
Handler_delete              0
Handler_discover            0
Handler_prepare             0
Handler_read_first          0
Handler_read_key            2
Handler_read_next           254
Handler_read_prev           0
Handler_read_rnd            0
Handler_read_rnd_next       0
Handler_rollback            0
Handler_savepoint           0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update              0
Handler_write               0
```

*Edit*
After re-arranging the index, the above query took ~1 second (the same 123 records) and these are the Handler results:

```
Variable_name               Value
Handler_commit              1
Handler_delete              0
Handler_discover            0
Handler_prepare             0
Handler_read_first          0
Handler_read_key            2
Handler_read_next           123
Handler_read_prev           0
Handler_read_rnd            0
Handler_read_rnd_next       0
Handler_rollback            0
Handler_savepoint           0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update              0
Handler_write               0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(First some comments; then a probable Answer.)

(4s is only 10x 400ms.)

How many rows have MemberNumber = 1234?  How many rows are returned from the query?

What value of `key_buffer_size` were you using?

Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'memberclaim'` for each engine.

The table, plus indexes, take about 50% more space than necessary if you could shrink all the `BIGINTs` to `INTs`.

Please run (and provide output from) this for each engine:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...;

FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

That will give some more clues of how many reads it is really doing.

**Timings**

If 254 records (in the data) are touched in 2.265 seconds, that says about 9ms/record, which is roughly the speed of spinning disks, when none are cached.  Please run the query twice in a row -- and see what the two timings are; probably the second one would be much faster, thereby confirming that the first run was non-cached.

Further 9ms/row implies that the rows are scattered around the table.  This is likely to happen in either MyISAM or InnoDB when the index being used does not 'track' the order of the data insertion.  Is the query in question the most important one?  If so, the performance can be fixed in the following way.  (Caution; the following will hurt performance on any *range scan* of `ClaimNumber`, but I suspect you don't do such.)

**Answer**

Change to InnoDB, so that the `PRIMARY KEY` is 'clustered' with the data and change from

```
PRIMARY KEY (ClaimNumber),
KEY idx_MemberNumber (MemberNumber, ServiceFrom, ServiceTo),
```

to

```
PRIMARY KEY (MemberNumber, ClaimNumber),
INDEX(ClaimNumber),
```

I *think* having all rows for `MemberNumber = 1234` "clustered" together will give you enough performance boost to make this worthwhile.  I left off the From and To; one of them could be added in the *middle* of the PK, but I don't think it will help a lot.

You will have about 100 rows per block.  If, say, there are 530 rows for `1234`, then that is 6 blocks to read -- about 60ms, which is a lot better than the 254 random blocks read (2265ms), as surmised above.  Shrinking all the `BIGINTs` to `INT UNSIGNED` would get you down to about 40ms.

If you have other `SELECTs` that look at multiple rows for a single "member", they will also run faster.

Added bonus:  Since fewer blocks are read for this query, other queries will find the cache (innodb_buffer_pool) more useful.

(This technique will not work for MyISAM because the data is not kept in any particular order.  Also, `UPDATEs` tend to further mangle the data.)  (Another note about MyISAM:  It has been removed from the next major release, 8.0.)

Comment: Thanks @Rick James. The data is not cached in my tests (I'm restarting the server between tests) because this query is almost always run from the HDD in the live environment unfortunately. The query is extremely quick once cached but it's usually only run per MemberNumber. It is by far the most important query against this table so I'll try this tonight and get back to you.

Comment: "Restart" makes sure the query is I/O-bound.  This is unrealistic for "production" timings.  I prefer to turn off the Query cache and run the query twice (production or non-production).

Comment: Thanks @Rick James! Switching the primary key to be (MemberNumber, ClaimNumber) lowered the query time from ~2 seconds to 200 milliseconds and it's blazingly fast now. Thanks a ton for the help, both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see in the question gives away how to improve the query

## OBSERVATION #1 : WHERE clause

```
WHERE MC.MemberNumber = 1234 AND
  MC.ServiceTo >= '2016-01-01' AND
  MC.ServiceFrom <= '2017-01-01';
```

## OBSERVATION #2 : Selected Index from EXPLAIN plan

```
KEY idx_MemberNumber (MemberNumber,ServiceFrom, ServiceTo),
```

What is the Query doing ? Since the `ServiceFrom` column appears before `ServiceTo` column in the index, the query optimizer is actually saying:

> Lookup every row that has MemberNumber `1234`, scanning the index in ascending order by `ServiceFrom` until it encounters `'2017-01-01'`. While scanning the index, it will then check the `ServiceTo` value to see if it is `2016-01-01` or greater.

If MemberNumber `1234` has data from years back in this table, the query will do such index scans every single time.

## SUGGESTION

#### Change the order of the last two columns

```
ALTER TABLE memberclaim ADD INDEX idx_MemberNumber2 (MemberNumber,ServiceTo,ServiceFrom);
```

This will help your query scan less index entries because it will start with ServiceTo `2016-01-01` for MemberNumber `1234`, rather than scanning until it hits ServiceFrom `2017-01-01`. After creating this index, run the EXPLAIN on it and this new index should be used.

If this helps, then you can drop the old index

```
ALTER TABLE memberclaim DROP INDEX idx_MemberNumber;
```

or you may keep this old index if other queries can benefit from it.

I would start with this before deep diving into InnoDB or SSD.

Comment: But according to the Handler numbers, only 254 rows (presumably in the index) were touched to get the 123 rows of output.  This says that the original index order was at least pretty good.  @TheCommunistCow - please run the Handler trick with Rolando's rearranged index.

Comment: Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA, that helped a good amount, the query went from 2-2.5 seconds to around 1 second, which is definitely better but still worse than the performance I got from MyISAM or SQL Server. I'll mark this as the accepted answer if no one has any other insights by tomorrow.

Comment: @Rick James I'll add the new handler results to the original post.

Comment: That implies that To is better at finding the rows than From.  But, look at the other occurrences of this query -- will they work as well, or does From sometimes work better?  It sounds like there are 123 rows with `ServiceTo >= '2016-01-01'` and 254-123 before that cutoff.  Meanwhile, none match `ServiceFrom <= '2017-01-01'`.

Comment: It is hard to optimize time ranges involving two columns.