# Is our MySQL poor performance related to excessive daily query cache prunes?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6, cache

We are experiencing a high number of query cache prunes per day, currently 80851746. MySQL really struggles even under a reasonable load of say 50+ concurrent connections.

The host is a Physical Server with SSDs configured as RAID 5, 24 cores and 128GB RAM. It is a dedicated MySQL 5.6 server and is accessed by various PHP clients.

The instance consists of 3 databases with a total size of 1TB, all tables are InnoDB and compressed.

I've included as much information as possible below, any advice would be much appreciated. I can provide more information if needed. Thanks.

### OS Information

```
# lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

# uname -a
Linux xxxxxxxxxx 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Memory Information

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        128915     128335        580          0        396      78764
-/+ buffers/cache:      49174      79740
Swap:        30517        192      30325
```

### CPU Information

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 0 @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x704
cpu MHz     : 1200.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 12
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 s
s ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eag
erfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadli
ne_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4999.98
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

# top
top - 10:48:41 up 94 days, 18:37,  5 users,  load average: 8.69, 9.65, 9.85
Tasks: 385 total,   1 running, 383 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu0  : 19.7 us,  5.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 71.3 id,  1.0 wa,  3.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  : 15.3 us,  3.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 81.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.3 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  : 24.1 us,  5.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 66.6 id,  1.0 wa,  2.7 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  : 12.7 us,  3.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.7 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  :  4.0 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 93.4 id,  0.3 wa,  0.3 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  : 14.7 us,  4.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 80.0 id,  0.7 wa,  0.7 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  : 17.1 us,  3.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 76.9 id,  1.7 wa,  0.7 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  : 42.5 us,  7.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 49.5 id,  0.7 wa,  0.3 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu8  : 37.3 us,  2.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 58.7 id,  0.7 wa,  0.7 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu9  : 33.3 us,  4.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 60.3 id,  0.3 wa,  1.7 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu10 : 17.3 us,  5.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 75.0 id,  0.7 wa,  2.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu11 : 17.7 us,  4.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 76.7 id,  1.3 wa,  0.3 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu12 :  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu13 : 17.8 us,  4.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 75.8 id,  0.0 wa,  2.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu14 :  1.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu15 :  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu16 : 25.3 us,  4.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 68.0 id,  0.3 wa,  2.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu17 :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu18 : 27.0 us,  1.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 71.3 id,  0.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu19 :  1.3 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu20 : 25.9 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 73.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu21 :  5.7 us,  2.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu22 : 51.3 us,  4.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 41.0 id,  0.7 wa,  2.3 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu23 : 35.3 us,  9.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 51.7 id,  1.0 wa,  2.3 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  13200956+total, 13146136+used,   548208 free,   406712 buffers
KiB Swap: 31250428 total,   198052 used, 31052376 free. 80715696 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                  
13928 mysql     20   0 56.424g 0.044t  10028 S 517.3 35.4   9937:02 mysqld                                                   
  540 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   6.0  0.0   2392:26 jbd2/sdb1-8
```

### Storage Information

```
# dmesg
[    6.615531] megasas: 0x1000:0x005b:0x1000:0x9266: bus 4:slot 0:func 0
[    6.742104] megasas: FW now in Ready state
[    6.784030] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 94 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784042] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 95 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784051] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 96 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784058] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 97 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784065] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 98 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784072] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 99 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784093] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 100 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784100] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 101 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784106] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 102 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784112] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 103 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784119] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 104 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784125] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 105 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784131] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 106 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784137] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 107 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784155] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 108 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784162] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: irq 109 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.784204] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: [scsi0]: FW supports<16> MSIX vector,Online CPUs: <24>,Current MSIX <16>
[    6.869100] md: multipath personality registered for level -4
[    6.893842] megasas:IOC Init cmd success
[    6.917873] megasas: INIT adapter done
[    6.989936] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: Controller type: MR,Memory size is: 1024MB
[    6.990092] scsi0 : LSI SAS based MegaRAID driver
[    6.990290] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     LSI      MR9266-8i        3.16 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    6.990374] scsi 0:0:1:0: Direct-Access     LSI      MR9266-8i        3.16 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    6.991442] scsi 0:0:17:0: Enclosure         LSI CORP SAS2X28          0717 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.002766] scsi 0:2:0:0: Direct-Access     LSI      MR9266-8i        3.16 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.002869] scsi 0:2:1:0: Direct-Access     LSI      MR9266-8i        3.16 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.008930] scsi 0:0:17:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 13
[    7.009066] sd 0:2:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    7.009080] sd 0:2:0:0: [sda] 2342125568 512-byte logical blocks: (1.19 TB/1.08 TiB)
[    7.009145] sd 0:2:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    7.009146] sd 0:2:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 1f 00 00 08
[    7.009188] sd 0:2:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    7.009212] sd 0:2:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    7.009230] sd 0:2:1:0: [sdb] 8197439488 512-byte logical blocks: (4.19 TB/3.81 TiB)
[    7.009289] sd 0:2:1:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    7.009290] sd 0:2:1:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 1f 00 00 08
[    7.009343] sd 0:2:1:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    7.017925]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
[    7.018501] sd 0:2:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    7.028790]  sdb: sdb1
[    7.029058] sd 0:2:1:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk

# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             63G   12K   63G   1% /dev
tmpfs            13G  1.1M   13G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        19G  5.3G   13G  31% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             63G   12K   63G   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda3       9.1G  2.7G  6.0G  31% /var
/dev/sdb1       3.8T  1.5T  2.1T  42% /data
tmpfs            48G   96K   48G   1% /mysql_tmp
```

### MySQL Information

```
# service mysql status
 * /usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.6.36-82.1, for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2009-2017 Percona LLC and/or its affiliates
Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version      5.6.36-82.1-log
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         1 day 1 hour 56 min 7 sec

Threads: 640  Questions: 730887058  Slow queries: 3189910  Opens: 3837  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 2006  Queries per second avg: 7828.109
```

### MySQL my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server            = utf8
collation-server                = utf8_unicode_ci
server-id                       = 20
user                            = mysql
pid-file                        = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                          = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
bind-address                    = 0.0.0.0
skip-name-resolve
tmpdir                          = /mysql_tmp
datadir                         = /data/mysql/
default-storage-engine          = InnoDB
myisam-recover-options          = FORCE,BACKUP

binlog_format                   = mixed
log_bin                         = /data/mysql/binlog/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days                = 4
sync_binlog                     = 1
slave-net-timeout               = 60

max-connections                 = 2000
interactive_timeout             = 14400
wait_timeout                    = 14400

tmp-table-size                  = 1024M
max-heap-table-size             = 1024M
query-cache-type                = 1
query-cache-size                = 33554432
thread-cache-size               = 100
open-files-limit                = 65535
table-definition-cache          = 4096
table-open-cache                = 4096
key-buffer-size                 = 32M
max-allowed-packet              = 16M
max-connect-errors              = 1000000

innodb-flush-method             = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group       = 2
innodb-log-file-size            = 4G
innodb-buffer-pool-size         = 40G
innodb-file-per-table           = 1
innodb_file-format              = Barracuda
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit  = 1
innodb_support_xa               = 1

log-error                       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-warnings                    = 2
slow-query-log                  = 1
slow-query-log-file             = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

### mysqltune Output

```
# mysqltuner 

 >>  MySQLTuner 1.1.1 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>

-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.6.36-82.1-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 778G (Tables: 399)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 52)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 80

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1d 2h 22m 29s (728M q [7K qps], 19M conn, TX: 1773B, RX: 95B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 80% / 20%
[--] Total buffers: 41.1G global + 1.1M per thread (2000 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 43.3G (34% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (3M/728M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 51% (1029/2000)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 32.0M/109.0K
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (1B cached / 15 reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 52.9% (301M cached / 569M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 80851746
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 1% (208K temp sorts / 13M sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 60354
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 49% (49M on disk / 98M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (9K created / 19M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 52% (2K open / 3K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (81/65K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (349M immediate / 349M locks)
[!!] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 778.6G/40.0G

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (> 32M)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 778G)
```

Comment: Is `long_query_time` set to the default of 10?  And you are getting ~30 "slow" queries per second?  Ouch.  Let's see (and work on) the slowest couple of queries.

Comment: @phil  Have you considered trying the Oct 2, 2017 Answer to modify query_cache_min_res_unit?  Your results?

Answer (score 3):

I would yes for one reason: ***InnoDB and the Query Cache are not good neighbors***. Why ?

On `Jun 07, 2014`, I answered the question [Why query_cache_type is disabled by default start from MySQL 5.6?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66774/why-query-cache-type-is-disabled-by-default-start-from-mysql-5-6/66796#66796). In that post, I poetically described how InnoDB man-handles the Query Cache. I originally got that information from [Pages 209-215 of High Performance MySQL (2nd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101716).

I have recommended people disable their query cache before:

- `Sep 25, 2013` : [invalidating query cache entries(key)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50467/invalidating-query-cache-entrieskey/55531#55531)
- `Sep 26, 2013` : [query cache hit value is not changing in my database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50290/query-cache-hit-value-is-not-changing-in-my-database/50535#50535)
- `Dec 23, 2013` : [MySQL with high CPU and memory usage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55524/mysql-with-high-cpu-and-memory-usage/55526#55526)

## RECOMMENDATIONS

Disable your query cache by setting [query_cache_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size) and [query_cache_type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_type) to 0. If things improve, all, well and good. If it does not improve, you must do three(3) things

- Set [query_cache_type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_type) back to 1
- [query_cache_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size)

  - You have it set right now at 32M (`33554432`)
  - Please increase it
- [query_cache_limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_limit)

  - You do not have it set. The default is 1M.
  - With a [query_cache_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size) of 32M, you can only hold, at the very least, 32 results that are 1M each. If you have smaller results sets going into the query cache, this might crowd the query cache and would cause lots of prunes because there is no elbow room for new incoming results sets.

## HEADS UP !!!

If you are using MySQL 5.7.19 or prior, please read the MySQL Documentation on [Query Cache Configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-configuration.html) for more authoritative advice.

[For all those using MySQL 5.7.20 and beyond, the query cache is deprecated and will go away](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-configuration.html).

Comment: Many thanks for the advice, much appreciated.

Comment: Don't increase `query_cache_size` too much -- it will slow down the prunes, thereby making the overall system slower.

Answer (score 1):

Rolando has already thoroughly covered your question about the query cache, but I thought that I would add that your value for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is probably too small for a dedicated server. You generally want to give as much RAM as possible to the InnoDB buffer pool.

At Engine Yard we set the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 85% of RAM on an instance of this size, although we also default to much smaller values for `tmp-table-size` and `max-heap-table-size` than you have here. That said, the output of `free -m` that you provided shows you have over 70GB of kernel disk cache, which would be better off handled by InnoDB directly.

I'd recommend testing with `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100G` as a fairly conservative value, and see if that helps. Whether it helps much is going to depend on your working set size; if you are regularly reading in much more than 100G of that 1TB dataset then it may not help you much, but if you are able to fit frequently accessed data in the buffer pool then you should see a boost!

Answer (score 1):

- `tmp_table_size` is dangerously large; lower it to, say, 100M.  (Don't increase the buffer_pool until you lower this!)
- Change `query_cache_type` to `DEMAND` and use `SQL_CACHE` on queries on tables that do not change frequently.  (`SQL_NO_CACHE` on other `SELECTs`)  This will cut back drastically on the prunes and increase the hit rate.
- Find the slow queries -- add composite indexes, reformulate, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce Query Cache Prunes,

```
SET GLOBAL VARIABLE query_cache_min_res_unit = 512;
```

to avoid using default size of 4096 characters per result.
Many more results will be stored before Query Cache prune becomes active.

And ADD to your my.cnf to cover the request on next shutdown/restart.

For additional specific recommendations, please add to your OP

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```